# AWS lambda input data doesn't get deserialized

Tags: java, aws-lambda, json-deserialization, serverless

I'm using the serverless framework for writing a AWS lambda function in Java.
My handler class looks like this:

```
public class ConstructionHandler implements RequestHandler<Location, 
ApiGatewayResponse> {

    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(ConstructionHandler.class);

    @Override
    public ApiGatewayResponse handleRequest(Location input, Context context) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            String locationJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(input);
            LOG.info("received: " + locationJson);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Exception occurred here: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // do something useful
        // return response
    }

}
```

My location object is a simple POJO described as the follwing:

```
public class Location {

    private double x;

    private double y;

    public Location(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Location() {

    }

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(double x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(double y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

}
```

The Lambda is configured in my serverless.yml like this:

```
functions:
  construct:
    handler: com.serverless.ConstructionHandler
    events:
      - http:
         path: /construct
         method: post
```

I used the Postman chrome plugin for fireing a POST-Request to the lambda, after deploying to AWS with the following request body:

{
    "x": 3.0,
    "y": 4.0
}

Unfortunately, if I go to Cloudwatch the logging says that the following object was deserialized:

{"x":0.0,"y":0.0}

Does anybody know why the original values got lost?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If you log `input.getX()` and `input.getY()` do you get the expected values?

Comment: Hello :) no, I also get 0.0

Comment: I don't  see anything obviously wrong in there. How is the API Gateway configured? In particular the input handling. Is there a mapping template? I don't have Postman handy, so what format does it send requests with? (multipart form, plain text....)